# print a tensor object of type (None, )

Tags: tensorflow, keras, printing, vgg-net

I am running in google colab and the tensor flow version is: `2.2.0` and the keras version is: `2.3.0-tf`

Question:
How can I print the value of `african_elephant_output`? I tried `print (african_elephant_output)`. This prints only the following:

`Tensor("Mul_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32)`

Location of Code is: [See code at In [31]](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.4-visualizing-what-convnets-learn.ipynb)

Relevant code is:

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
    from keras import backend as K
    from keras.preprocessing import image
    from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf
    print (tf.__version__)
    print (tf.keras.__version__)
    
    # The local path to our target image
    img_path = '/content/pic.jpg'
    
    # `img` is a PIL image of size 224x224
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    
    # `x` is a float32 Numpy array of shape (224, 224, 3)
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    
    # We add a dimension to transform our array into a "batch"
    # of size (1, 224, 224, 3)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    
    # Finally we preprocess the batch
    # (this does channel-wise color normalization)
    x = preprocess_input(x)
    
    K.clear_session()
    
    # Note that we are including the densely-connected classifier on top;
    # all previous times, we were discarding it.
    model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')
    
    preds = model.predict(x)
    print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])
    
    np.argmax(preds[0])
    # this prints 386
    
    # This is the "african elephant" entry in the prediction vector
    african_elephant_output = model.output[:, 386]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Tensorflow documentation and my experience you should be able to get the contents of a Tensor using `.numpy()` API. So `african_elephant_output.numpy()`.
You can also check the tutorial from Tensorflow [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) for reference.

Comment: `print (african_elephant_output).numpy()` does not work. I get the error `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`. I have eager execution enabled by default

Comment: Could you check for me what you receive when you execute `tf.executing_eagerly()` statement before `print(african_elephant_output.numpy())` and let me know if you receive `True` or `False`.

Comment: It's `True`. The tensorflow version is 2.2.0.                                        By the way, the value of `african_elephant_output` is a float32 with value 0.909                                                                              `print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0][0][2])` from the vector: `Predicted: [[('n02504458', 'African_elephant', 0.90942043), ('n01871265', 'tusker', 0.08618348), ('n02504013', 'Indian_elephant', 0.004354588)]]`

Comment: But yes, using  `print(african_elephant_output.numpy())` - we  should print `print(african_elephant_output.numpy())` and this value should be `0.90942043`

Comment: Sorry I got a bit confused, is it working with `numpy()` or not? If Not I will suggest could you create a google colab so that I can debug your issue.